# How to disable color dithering for low-bit-depth screen settings?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I am using Terminal Services and TeamViewer a lot to access other computers, partly over slow networks. The problem described below is not affected by which of the two remote access services I am using.

When accessing Windows 7 Professional machines, a great deal of text is hard to read as the background is dithered. Even for exactly the same colors, Windows 2003 does not seem to dither at all, but to choose the closest available color. I strongly prefer the latter, as I don't care for the exact colors, I just want to be able to read easily. I am not sure whether this is operating system-related.

The programs on the remote systems do not allow me to change the color choices for the various backgrounds to anything sane.

Is there a way to disable this color dithering using some target operating system setting that will do the trick for **both** Terminal Services and TeamViewer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting View → Quality → Custom Settings → Edit Custom Settings and experimenting with the settings there?

Also when remoted in, go to View → Scaling → Original to set the size. I find this makes it better for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, raising the color depth setting in the mentioned location in the Terminal Services Client helps with dithering, but the screen transfer appears to be a little slower. It does not help with TeamViewer connections though. My hope was to find out about some target operating system setting that will do the trick for both Terminal Services and TeamViewer and I have adjusted my question that way.